# Introducir elementos de tamaño variable a un ArrayList en un constructor JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Pues necesito llenar un **ArrayList** de objetos tipo *Fruta* a través de un constructor y no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Adjunto el código.

```
enum Frutas {


FRESA, SANDIA, PLATANO, MELOCOTON, PERA;
}

public class Premio {

    private final int cantidad;
    private ArrayList<Frutas> combinacion;

    public Premio(int cantidad, Frutas... nFrutas) {
        this.cantidad=cantidad;
        this.combinacion = new ArrayList<Frutas>();

    }

    public ArrayList<Frutas> getCombinacion(){
        return this.combinacion;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para realizar lo que deseas, modifica de esta manera tu constructor:

```
public Premio(int cantidad, Frutas... nFrutas) {
  this.cantidad=cantidad;
  //Llena ArrayList  
  this.combinacion = new ArrayList<Frutas>(Arrays.asList(nFrutas));
}
```

de esta forma envías un array que conviertes a listado de objetos `Fruta` y lo asignas a `combinacion`.

Comment: Si, esto me ha servido, estaba usando bucles for y no tenía ni idea de como hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public Premio(int cantidad, int seleccion) {
   Frutas selectedFruta = Frutas.values()[seleccion];
   this.combinacion = new ArrayList<Frutas>();
   this.combinacion.add(selectedFruta);
}
```

Comment: Lo que quiero es pasarle al constructor un numero X de Frutas para que se añadan a esa ArrayList y poder hacer como una combinación ganadora al crear el objeto Premio. Por ejemplo meter 3 FRESAS.